# Web Server(IIS) role grayed out

Tags: windows-server-2008

as my web server doesn't serve static contents I wanted to see which service were associated. 
Unfortunately, I see that the web server is grayed out [image: web serer is grayed out]

How can I enable the services inside it?
The Server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Service pack 1.

I would like to change the service inside Web Server. As it is grayed out I cannot change the services associated as in this picture:

[image: I would like to change the service inside Web Server. As it is grayed out I cannot see the services as in this picture]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about not being able to read the Add features dialogue properly.

Comment: Yes it is about not being able to read the Add services because it's grayed out.I don't see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS role is installed, and you can manage its services from the homepage. You have this information displayed in the window.